# Writing mouse location to QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

How can I write append mouse click coordinates to a `QTableWidget` with each click?  I already have the `QMouseEvent` to display the coordinates in a `QLabelItem`, but I would like to add a row with the coordinates of each click.  Is this possible?  I know I would need to use `setItem()` but how do I attach this to the existing mouse click event?

Here's the event filter that I have for the mouse clicks:

```
   def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.p1 and event.type() == event.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            if event.button()==Qt.LeftButton:
                pos=event.scenePos()
                x=((pos.x()*(2.486/96))-1)
                y=(pos.y()*(10.28/512))
                self.label.setText("x=%0.01f,y=%0.01f" %(x,y))
       #here is where I get lost with creating an iterator to append to the table with each click
             for row in range(10):
                for column in range(2):
                    self.coordinates.setItem(row,column,(x,y))
```

Comment: You want to **add** a new row each time, or you want to update existing cells?

Comment: add a new row... I'm not so good with the iteration, so that's where I keep getting stuck

Comment: Why do you want to add the same `(x,y)` string value to multiple cells in the table? Is that your goal or do you just want to add a single new cell in a new row?

Comment: I just want to add a single new cell... hm..

Comment: So, a new row where the first column cell has the (x,y) string and the rest are blank for future data? Maybe you should update the question with the shape of your table and where you want this specific data to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a two-column table for the `x,y` values, and you want to append a new row with each click:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.p1 and event.type() == event.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            pos = event.scenePos()
            x = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(
                '%0.01f' % ((pos.x() * 2.486 / 96) - 1))
            y = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(
                '%0.01f' % (pos.y() * 10.28 / 512))
            row = self.coordinates.rowCount()
            self.coordinates.insertRow(row)
            self.coordinates.setItem(row, 0, x)
            self.coordinates.setItem(row, 1, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `model=QTableView.model()`, you could append a new row to your table with something like:

```
nbrows = model.rowCount()
model.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),nbrows,nbrows)
item = QStandardItem("({0},{1})".format(x,y))
model.insertRow(nbrows, item.index())
model.endInsertRows()
```

If you have a `QTableWidget` and not a `QTableView`, you could use the same MO:

- Append a new row with `self.insertRow(self.rowCount())`
- Use the `.setItem` method to modify the data of your last row. You could use for example `QTableWidgetItem("({0},{1})".format(x,y))`, or whatever string you like to represent your tuple of coordinates.

However, I'd advise you to start using a `QTableView`s instead of a `QTableWidget`, as it offers far more flexibility.

Comment: I have the feeling it is a QTableWidget because of the setItem method.

Comment: Indeed, the OP mentioned it. I had overlooked that.

Comment: neither is set in stone; I could easily ditch it for a QTableView...I agree, probably the better choice.  Thank you!